# ASP.net logout doesn't work

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.net application where i want user to login and logout. Now the problem is that when a user press the logout hyperlink he doesn't logout.

Logoff.aspx:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
    Session.RemoveAll()
    Session.Abandon()
    Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "10;URL=~/Account/Login.aspx")
End Sub
```

This code just redirects to Login.aspx but he remains logged in! What could it be that i forgot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

You can probably remove most of the code you have there other than the Session.Abandon();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx

Comment: No i made my own login page i don't use the Standard login of asp so .signout doesn't work :(

Comment: @schoen - how do you expect us to know how to log you out when we don't know how you are logging in?  If you're not using the FormsAuthentication, then only you know how to fix it.

Comment: @schoen can you please include your code for how you sign-in a user?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry Here you go

    ` Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim BLLUsers As New BLLUsers
        Dim username As String = txtUsername.Text
        Dim password As String = txtPasswoord.Text


        If BLLUsers.Login(username, password) = True Then
            Session("Username") = username
            Response.Redirect("~/Overview/OpenBugs.aspx")
        End If



    End Sub`

Btw How do i format code here? That backtick doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Still doesn't help. You need to know what your BLLUsers.Login is doing. It might be creating a cookie, that you need to expire on your Logout page.